# SQL |How to splint single dates column into two columns in a SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Thanks for looking at my query, I need some suggestions on below:

- How to splint single dates column into two columns in TSQL
- I have SQL table which is a  hotel CheckInDate the problem this records in include CheckOutDate which is recorded in the same column but with record id, so every id will have two rows of records in one column.
- I want to splint this date based on two columns (CheckInDate and CheckOutDate), CheckOutDate will be the second column will be an alias.
- I would like to see all the records based on their id.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Original Table

This is results I would like to see, the last column is date diff, DATEDIFF(d,[Date],[Date]) AS DaysBooked

Original Table Fields

```
SELECT  
    [ID]
    ,([Date])  AS CheckInDate
  FROM [DateOneRow]
```

I tried below code below code but dd not work

```
SELECT  
--I would like to have below to columns
    ([ID])
     ,MIN([Date])     AS CheckInDate
     ,MAX([DATE])     AS CheckOutDate
     ,DATEDIFF(d,[Date],[Date]) AS DaysBooked
  FROM [DateOneRow]
  GROUP BY      [ID],  ([Date])
```

[Original Table]
[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFjbC.png)

**DDL added by @shawnt00**

```
create table DateOneRow (Id int not null, "Date" date not null);
insert into DateOneRow ("Date", Id) values
    ('20181201', 1), ('20181204', 1),
    ('20180201', 2), ('20180301', 2),
    ('20180301', 1), ('20180303', 1),
    ('20180402', 2), ('20180503', 2),
    ('20180120', 2), ('20180202', 2);
```

Comment: So the SAME `date` field has two meanings: "Check In Date" and also means "Check Out Date". This is a horrible design.

Comment: There apparently is also missing a column indicating which rows belong to one booking.

Comment: I think it's very likely there are other columns in your table that help make it clear if the Date column is a checkin or checkout. Please give us more information on the columns in your table.

Comment: Totally agree this is a horrible design, unfortunately, the table has only two fields  [ID], ([Date]).@MatBailie

Comment: Is this really for MySQL? The "[" and "]" suggest SQL Server. Also the screenshots look like SSMS. Please correct the tag, if you're actually using SQL Server. (But instead of screenshot you should have used text anyway.)

Comment: @ sticky bit  corrected and much appreciatted for commenting

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't condone this bad database design, here's a query that will show you what you need.

**For SQL Server:**

```
create table [DateOneRow] (
  [Id] int,
  [Date] date
);

insert into [DateOneRow] ([Id], [Date]) values (1, '2018-01-01');
insert into [DateOneRow] ([Id], [Date]) values (1, '2018-01-03');
insert into [DateOneRow] ([Id], [Date]) values (2, '2018-02-15');
insert into [DateOneRow] ([Id], [Date]) values (2, '2018-02-16');
insert into [DateOneRow] ([Id], [Date]) values (3, '2018-03-20');
insert into [DateOneRow] ([Id], [Date]) values (4, '2018-04-25');

select
    ci.id,
    check_in,
    check_out,
    datediff(day, check_in, check_out) as days_booked
  from (
    select id, min(date) as check_in from dateonerow group by id
  ) ci
  full join (
    select id, max(date) as check_out from dateonerow group by id
  ) co on ci.id = co.id
```

Result:

```
id  check_in    check_out   days_booked
--  ----------  ----------  -----------
1   2018-01-01  2018-01-03  2
2   2018-02-15  2018-02-16  1
3   2018-03-20  2018-03-20  0
4   2018-04-25  2018-04-25  0
```

**For MySQL:**

```
create table DateOneRow (
  Id int,
  Date date
);

insert into DateOneRow (Id, Date) values (1, '2018-01-01');
insert into DateOneRow (Id, Date) values (1, '2018-01-03');
insert into DateOneRow (Id, Date) values (2, '2018-02-15');
insert into DateOneRow (Id, Date) values (2, '2018-02-16');
insert into DateOneRow (Id, Date) values (3, '2018-03-20');
insert into DateOneRow (Id, Date) values (4, '2018-04-25');

select 
    ci.id, 
    ci.check_in, 
    co.check_out, 
    datediff(check_out, check_in) as days_booked
  from (
    select id, min(date) as check_in from DateOneRow group by id
  ) ci
  join (
    select id, max(date) as check_out from DateOneRow group by id
  ) co on ci.id = co.id;
```

Result:

```
id  check_in    check_out   days_booked
--  ----------  ----------  -----------
1   2018-01-01  2018-01-03  2
2   2018-02-15  2018-02-16  1
3   2018-03-20  2018-03-20  0
4   2018-04-25  2018-04-25  0
```

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If we only had a booking ID it would be fairly easy. But we can derive a booking number for an `[Id]` (I guess this is the client who booked?) with

```
ceiling(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [DateOneRow].[Id] ORDER BY [DateOneRow].[CheckInDate]) / convert(decimal, 2))
```

`row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [DateOneRow].[Id] ORDER BY [DateOneRow].[CheckInDate])` will number the rows for an `[Id]` ordered by the `[CheckInDate]`. Every two rows (in the order defined by `[CheckInDate]`) belong to one booking. So we can divide the number by 2 and `ceiling()` it, to get a booking number the row belongs to.

With that we can easily `GROUP BY [Id]` and the booking number, taking the minimum date as checkin time and the maximum as checkout time. Apply the `datediff()` on that and you're done.

```
SELECT [X].[Id],
       min([X].[CheckInDate]) [CheckInDate],
       max([X].[CheckInDate]) [CheckOutDate],
       datediff(d, min([X].[CheckInDate]), max([X].[CheckInDate])) [DaysBooked]
       FROM (SELECT [DateOneRow].[Id],
                    [DateOneRow].[CheckInDate],
                    ceiling(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [DateOneRow].[Id]
                                               ORDER BY [DateOneRow].[CheckInDate]) / convert(decimal, 2)) [Booking#]
                    FROM [DateOneRow]) [X]
       GROUP BY [X].[Id],
                [X].[Booking#];
```

(You might consider using `datediff(d, min([X].[CheckInDate]), max([X].[CheckInDate])) + 1 [DaysBooked]` (note the `+ 1`), if the dates are inclusive.)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=80d654663062ee7f34e1a836eb87ecf1)

But I strongly recommend to revise that horrible design!

---

Edit:

If `[Id]` actually is a booking ID and the same only for the two rows belonging to one booking, it'll be a simple `GROUP BY` using `min()` and `max()`.

```
SELECT [DateOneRow].[Id],
       min([DateOneRow].[CheckInDate]) [CheckInDate],
       max([DateOneRow].[CheckInDate]) [CheckOutDate],
       datediff(d, min([DateOneRow].[CheckInDate]), max([DateOneRow].[CheckInDate])) [DaysBooked]
       FROM [DateOneRow]
       GROUP BY [DateOneRow].[Id];
```

Comment: Apologies ID is meant to be Booking ID.

Comment: @SQLfun: Then why does the same ID appear more than twice in your screenshot of the base table?

Answer (score 0):

If your check-ins are always correctly paired up with a check-out then something like this should work:

```
-- option 1
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by Id order by "Date") - 1 as rn
    from DateOneRow
)
select
    d1."Date" as CheckInDate, d2."Date" as CheckOutDate,
    datediff(day, d1."Date", d2."Date") as DaysBooked
from data d1 inner join data d2 on d2.Id = d1.Id and d2.rn = d1.rn + 1
where d1.rn % 2 = 0;


-- option 2
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by Id order by "Date") - 1 as rn
    from DateOneRow
)
select
    d1."Date" as CheckInDate, d2."Date" as CheckOutDate,
    datediff(day, d1."Date", d2."Date") as DaysBooked
from data d1 cross apply
    (
    select min("Date") as "Date" from data
    where Id = d1.Id and "Date" > d1."Date"
    ) d2
where d1.rn % 2 = 0;
```

I'm giving you the second option in case it's faster.

http://rextester.com/LHSZ1605

Comment: Many thanks for your time and effort much appreciated.